# Same row dimensions in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to explain it as best I can. I'm using bootstrap. I have two columns, one on the left is a image and the other on the right is a title and description. I need to make the photo fill the entire available area of the column and automatically increase its height when adding more text. Something like a cover. Thanks

I tried to add the height of the image in CSS, but then it has one constant value and it is supposed to be dynamic.[how it look like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnDxO.jpg)

```
    <div id="audi" class="row mt-4">
    <!-- Miejsce na karuzelę -->
    <div class="col-md-9 addpadding">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <!-- Wskaźniki (indicators) -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Slajdy karuzeli -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="car.jpg" alt="Audi - Zdjęcie 1" class="img-fluid custom-carousel-image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="car1.jpg" alt="Audi - Zdjęcie 2" class="img-fluid custom-carousel-image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="car2.jpg" alt="Audi - Zdjęcie 3" class="img-fluid custom-carousel-image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Strzałki nawigacyjne -->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Poprzedni</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Następny</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- Miejsce na tytuł i opis po prawej stronie -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100">
                <h2 class="pb-1 car-title">Audi</h2>
                <!-- Pill Badges w jednej linii z wyśrodkowaniem -->
                <div class="align-items-center mb-1 mt-1">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-ultra mr-1"><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp2022</span>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-ultra mr-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-fire-flame-simple"></i>&nbsp310 KM</span>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-ultra mr-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-shuffle"></i>&nbspAutomatyczna</span>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-ultra"><i class="fa-solid fa-gas-pump"></i>&nbspBenzyna</span>
                </div>
                <p class="car-description mt-1">opis.</p>
                <!-- Przycisk "Dowiedz się więcej" -->
                <a href="#" class="btn-learn-more mt-1">Sprawdź</a>
                <div class="mt-3">
                    <h2 class="rent-info">Warunki</h2>
                    <ul class="rent-info-list">
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i>1.</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i>2.</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i>3</li>
                        <li><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i>4.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
<div class="mt-2">
    <h2 class="priceHeader">Cennik</h2>
    <ul class="price-list">
        <li><strong>Doba:</strong>1 zł</li>
    </ul>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel {
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. We don't debug images here.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `height: 100%` on the parent container of your `<img>`'s and `object-fit: cover;` + `max-height: 100%` on the `<img>`'s.

[documentation for object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit?retiredLocale=de)

Comment: I tried, doesn't work

Comment: [Could you then please provide a working code snippet to reproduce the issue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do/358993#358993)

Comment: okay, I made a mistake. it works, thanks :)